# Version declaration in parent POM

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Which is the suitable tag to declare version of dependencies used in child POM, i.e. Properties tag or DependencyManagement tag? What are their respective pros n con's? Is there any better way?

Comment: You obviously don't mean "tag or tag"?

Comment: DependencyManagement is the correct way which means you don't need to define the version in child's. Furthermore you have only a single point of location where you need to change things. Apart from that you can do some kinf of exlusions etc. only at a single point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare them as one of the `property`

```
<properties>
   <commons.dbcp.version>somenumber</commons.dbcp.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: And then use the property to aet dependency management in the same parent.